# Default android studio 1.4 Navigation Drawer with tab tab is not displaying

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am new to android,first sorry fr my bad English ,I using Default Navigation Drawer its working fine in my main fragment i try to show 2 tabs with in first fragment ,but my problem was my swipe pager is working my tab toolbar was not visible ,and 
one more thing is when i user my Frame Layout with in Tool bar my tab was visible but my list content was not scrolling ,when i use Frame Layout out side Of Tool Bar my Tabs visible but my list content was not scrolling any one help me how to resolve this 
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements TabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
    //you can leave it empty
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TabFragment fragment=new TabFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

TabFragment

```
 public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 2 ;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public TabFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return x;
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new Primary();
            case 1 : return new Primary();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Primary";
            case 1 :
                return "Social";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
       />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

tab_layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicator"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorSelectedText"
    app:tabTextColor="#f4f0f4"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

For identification draw a line rounder line when i use frame layout with in app bar Layout my tabs was Visible by my list content was not scrolling  when i use my frame layout out side app bar Layout

[click here for image my output like this but not visible tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fyOE.png)

Comment: where is tab_layout xml file ?